# Django temporary view

Tags: python, django

In my Django Project user is redirect to specific template with content:

> "Thanks for your registration"

```
def success_signup(request):
    """Account created with success."""
    return render(request, "account/success.html")
```

when he register new account with **success**.

I want to make this template/view *temporary*.

I.E When the user/somebody go to

> "account/success.html"

again should be redirected to the homepage instead of the success.html template.

Unfortunately, I can not find this in the documentation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time pass a get variable first_time=yes. Then check `if first_time == "yes"`, Show this page `elif request.user.is_authenticated` return back to index page `else` redirect to login page.

url should look like this

```
localhost:8000/success-signup/?first_time=yes
```

views.py

```
def success_signup(request):
   first_time = request.GET.get('first_time')

   if first_time == "yes":
        """Account created with success."""
        return render(request, "account/success.html")
   elif request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
   else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signup'))
```